# ln-Function in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I'd like to plot the function

`f(x)=\ln \left(\frac{1}{2} \frac{x-2}{x}\right)`

using `TikZ`. Can someone help me what the correct syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=-5:-0.05] {.5 * (x-2) / x};
    \addplot[domain=0.05:5] {.5 * (x-2) / x};    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. An additional question: How would I insert the natural logarithm for the whole exprecion?

Comment: @Averroes2 If you add the `ln` around the function like so `ln(.5 * (x-2) / x)` and adjust the range to `2.05:5` for the second plot.